# Joining different WHERE clauses on mySQL multiple select statement

Tags: mysql

As someone who constantly has problems with databases, I'm trying to look for a solution that optimizes my database calls. Scenario is this, I'm trying to get all rows of items directly owned by the user, but also I want to get the rows of items where the user roles acts as a guest. My current query works, but I think it isn't the best forged solution for what I'm trying to achieve. This get me the results I want, but I fear when there are hundreds of rows this will get terribly slow

```
set @UsrId = 23;
(SELECT Eventos.Fecha, Eventos.InformacionDelEvento, Eventos.PosicionGpsSiNo, Eventos.InformacionGps, Dispositivos.Nombre, CatalogoDeEventos.Descripcion
FROM Eventos, CatalogoDeEventos, Dispositivos, DispositivosxUsuario
WHERE Eventos.IdEvento = CatalogoDeEventos.Id 
AND Dispositivos.IdentificadorUnico = Eventos.IdDispositivo
AND DispositivosxUsuario.IdDispositivo = Dispositivos.Id
AND Dispositivos.Invisible = 0
AND DispositivosxUsuario.IdUsuario = @UsrId
ORDER BY Fecha DESC)
UNION
(SELECT Eventos.Fecha, Eventos.InformacionDelEvento, Eventos.PosicionGpsSiNo, Eventos.InformacionGps, Dispositivos.Nombre, CatalogoDeEventos.Descripcion
FROM Eventos, CatalogoDeEventos, Dispositivos, DispositivosxUsuario, Seguidores
WHERE Eventos.IdEvento = CatalogoDeEventos.Id 
AND Dispositivos.IdentificadorUnico = Eventos.IdDispositivo
AND DispositivosxUsuario.IdDispositivo = Dispositivos.Id
AND Dispositivos.Invisible = 0
AND Seguidores.IdUsuario = DispositivosxUsuario.IdUsuario
AND Seguidores.IdSeguidor = @UsrId
ORDER BY Fecha DESC)
```

So both queries have this same block

```
SELECT Eventos.Fecha, Eventos.InformacionDelEvento, Eventos.PosicionGpsSiNo, Eventos.InformacionGps, Dispositivos.Nombre, CatalogoDeEventos.Descripcion
FROM Eventos, CatalogoDeEventos, Dispositivos, DispositivosxUsuario
WHERE Eventos.IdEvento = CatalogoDeEventos.Id 
AND Dispositivos.IdentificadorUnico = Eventos.IdDispositivo
AND DispositivosxUsuario.IdDispositivo = Dispositivos.Id
AND Dispositivos.Invisible = 0
```

They differ on the lines above this, so far I haven't figured a way of getting both results on a single call

Comment: Use modern `JOIN` syntax, rather than a query style that was outdated 20 years ago; it would make it obvious you can likely `LEFT JOIN Sequidores`

Comment: @Uueerdo I'm still learning databases, if you can could you link me documentation (or examples), I have tried reading the Oracle's, but I'm still too newbie to understand it fully

Comment: I went ahead and re-wrote the query using the newer join syntax. @Uueerdo is right, it's a lot easier to read.

Comment: MySQL's official online documentation is actually pretty good in my experience, but I can understand; starting out it is difficult to even know what to search for. [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is a good place to start, the "tree" on the left side of the page even has a sub branch specifically for JOINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
SELECT Eventos.Fecha, Eventos.InformacionDelEvento, Eventos.PosicionGpsSiNo,     Eventos.InformacionGps, Dispositivos.Nombre, CatalogoDeEventos.Descripcion
FROM Eventos, CatalogoDeEventos, Dispositivos, DispositivosxUsuario, Seguidores
WHERE Eventos.IdEvento = CatalogoDeEventos.Id 
    AND Dispositivos.IdentificadorUnico = Eventos.IdDispositivo
    AND DispositivosxUsuario.IdDispositivo = Dispositivos.Id
    AND Dispositivos.Invisible = 0
    AND Seguidores.IdUsuario = DispositivosxUsuario.IdUsuario
    AND (
      (Seguidores.IdUsuario = DispositivosxUsuario.IdUsuario 
        AND Seguidores.IdSeguidor = @UsrId) 
      OR DispositivosxUsuario.IdUsuario = @UsrId)
ORDER BY Fecha DESC
```

as was mentioned in the comments, this effectively left joins on Sequidores and that would probably have been more obvious if the query was written with the newer join syntax.

Re-written to use newer join syntax

```
SELECT e.Fecha, e.InformacionDelEvento, e.PosicionGpsSiNo, e.InformacionGps, d.Nombre, cde.Descripcion
FROM Eventos e 
    INNER JOIN CatalogoDeEventos cde ON e.IdEvento = cde.Id
    INNER JOIN Dispositivos d ON d.IdentificadorUnico  = e.IdDispositivo
    INNER JOIN DispositivosxUsuario du ON du.IdDispositivo = d.Id
    LEFT JOIN Seguidores s ON s.IdUsuario = du.IdUsuario 
WHERE d.Invisible = 0 
  AND (Seguidores.IdSeguidor = @UsrId 
        OR DispositivosxUsuario.IdUsuario = @UsrId)
ORDER BY Fecha DESC
```

Comment: Its great I can compare both queries to fully understand one another and do the other ones.

Comment: Glad I could help :)